# Human trials for stentrode neural recordings

Tags: neurology, electrophysiology

Neural recording via a [stentrode](http://www.nature.com/nbt/journal/v34/n3/full/nbt.3428.html) seems to be next big thing in neuroscience. It can be used to treat disabilities, brain disorders and enable brain to brain communications. Are human trials being done at large scale at various universities?